# Sipdroid documentation android - STUN server

Tags: android, documentation, voip, sip

I am currently working on SipDroid for private purposes (yet fully agreeing to the OpenSource licensing). I have several problems with this : aside an enormous lack of documentation, it seems that the project in it's release version can not be built simply easily. 
I managed though to get it compiled without Eclipse yelling at me.

Now, after adding some heavy logging of the process, it seems the IP adress recovered from the active connection is not correct : which is why I ask this question.

With two devices (HTC magic with 2.2 and Nexus S with 2.3.4) on the same WLAN, the magic returns the public IP, and the Nexus returns his local IP, which is obviously no good for any SIP registration... any idea why i don't get the same data ?

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        en.hasMoreElements();)  { 
    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();
        enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
    ...
```

I used a STUN Server to get its correct IP, but now the RTPStream Sender and Receiver are gone mad...

Joining the google group didn't help me a lot and my question is still unanswered...

As googling only brought me tutorials on setting up the app for each and every SIP account,  if any one has any documentation about the SipDroid source it would really be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging over and over again and again ... still no regularity in this error : all i can say is that the registering/messaging part of the sip stack in SipDroid

- by default sets the contact URL to 127.0.0.1,
- if connected to a proper network returns it's local IP on a nexus S with Android 2.3.4 (Android 2.3.4 generally ???)
- if connected to a proper network returns it's local IP on a HTC Magic with Android 2.2 and a Motorola XT701 with 2.1.

...

I feel like I'm wasting a .... plenty of time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call [isSiteLocalAddress()](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.1_r1_src/java/net/Inet4Address.html#isSiteLocalAddress%28%29) to filter your local ip on the nexus S ?

Cheers